# Doubt in Zeeman effect for sodium spectrum

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy

I am reading an [atomic molecular physics book](https://pdfcoffee.com/atomic-and-molecular-spectra-laser-by-rajkumarpdf-pdf-free.html) (for Indian universities). You may not familiar with it. But you can download it from the link if you wish.

So in the book it is mentioned that for normal Zeeman effect, transition between any two spin singlet states $ (S=0) $ results in a 3 component splitting, one $  \pi $ and two $ \sigma $ depending upon the selection rules.

They also tell us about the polarisation state of emitted radiation.
The $\pi$ component transition refers to electric field **parallel** to applied magnetic field and $\sigma$ component transition refers to electric field **perpendicular** to applied magnetic field.

Same kind of components appear in case of Sodium atom for anomalous zeeman effect, as shown in fig. below.

[image]

But their polarisation conditions are not explicitly mentioned. So can I assume that in this case of Sodium atom the $\pi$ and $\sigma$ components have the usual polarisation meaning i.e. parallel and perpendicular to magnetic field, as in normal Zeeman effect.

Comment: +1 clearly stated question

Comment: May I direct you to the article? *The life of π and σ—A tutorial review of the ubiquitous use of these symbols in Zeeman and magnetic-resonance spectroscopy*, https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/cmr.a.20105. It addresses your query in detail.

Comment: @AChem Thanks. Really helpful